# xltm workbook open directly to named sub

Tags: excel, vba

how do you open an xltm workbook that goes directly to the vba editor then to the module named "Module1" then to a sub named "test" ?

**UPDATE SOLVED** from FaneDuru adopted to an open workbook sub

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim wb As Workbook, TestPrLineNo As Long
   
   Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True 'show VBE

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks.Open(wbFullName)       'open it and set its wb object
   
   wb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Activate 'activate the necessary module
   TestPrLineNo = Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.ProcBodyLine("Test", 0) 'find the code line of the "Test" procedure
   Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.CodePane.SetSelection TestPrLineNo + 1, _
                                                                 1, TestPrLineNo, 1 'select the procedure first code line
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, show us what you try by your own. Then, why do you need this scenario?

Comment: @FaneDuru my purpose is when i want to create macros often i always open the file press alt+f11 then select the module then to the named sub, this process makes it more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next way:

```
Sub SelectProcedureInWB_Module()
   Dim wb As Workbook, wbFullName As String, TestPrLineNo As Long
   
   Application.vbE.MainWindow.Visible = True 'show VBE

   wbFullName = "MyWB Template.xltm"         'use here your workbook full name
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFullName)       'open it and set its wb object
   
   wb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Activate 'activate the necessary module
   TestPrLineNo = Application.vbE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.ProcBodyLine("Test", 0) 'find the code line of the "Test" procedure
   Application.vbE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.CodePane.SetSelection TestPrLineNo + 1, _
                                                                 1, TestPrLineNo, 1 'select the procedure first code line
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it...

But, when somebody asks a clarification question, it is at least polite to answer it. Even saying "I do not know where from to start" and "I only want learning"...

Comment: hi, thank you it works adopted it to an open workbook sub and my apologies was not able to reply right away i had errands to do so i was away from my pc, thanks again

Comment: i have added a userform to my personal.xlsb, the code runs fine and still finds the test sub but somehow the window shown in the vb editor is now the userform of the personal.xlsb instead of the test sub of the xltm file, if i go and check the test sub inside the module of the xltm file the "test" is highlighted meaning it finds it but somehow switches the window shown to the userform of the personal.xlsb

Comment: @k1dr0ck Without seeing the code you use, I cannot imagine what mistake is there... It should do what the above code does independent of the place where the code exists. Do you use **exactly** the above code, **without any modification, even if it looks minor to you**? If yes, and you have AnyDesk installed, I will like to connect to your computer and see what's happening, if you allow such a connection. If not, please place another question posting your existing code and tag me here (@FaneDuru). If I will be available I will try helping. If not, maybe somebody else will solve it...

Comment: im actually using the workbook open code in my main post, the way i open it is, excel is not already open, i double click the xltm file in my desktop, when the file opens it shows the form of the personal.xlsb in the vbe editor, when i go to the module of my xltm file  the test sub is highlighted meaning it does find it, its ok if there is no fix it is just a minor problem

Comment: @k1dr0ck I cannot understand anything, sorry... If you **manually** open the template, how **a similar code with the one above is called and how does it use the open workbook as reference**? The above code cannot be used as it is if the template is already open...

Comment: @k1dr0ck Since, you look to not use the above code, as it is, if you want to solve the issue, you should follow my second suggestion. the one related to an new question containing the code you use and good explanations about the testing environment.

Comment: thanks but i think there is no need to post a new question, it is just a minor problem

Comment: @k1dr0ck Since you consider it being minor and I do not know what and how you try doing, I cannot help. I wish you a good day!